# Rounded Corners on UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, image-manipulation

I'm trying to draw images on the iPhone using with rounded corners, a la the contact images in the Contacts app. I've got code that generally work, but it occasionally crashes inside of the UIImage drawing routines with an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` - `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`. I thought this might be related to the [cropping question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage) I asked a few weeks back, but I believe I'm setting up the clipping path correctly.

Here's the code I'm using - when it doesn't crash, the result looks fine and anybody looking to get a similar look is free to borrow the code.

```
- (UIImage *)borderedImageWithRect: (CGRect)dstRect radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    UIImage *maskedImage = nil;

    radius = MIN(radius, .5 * MIN(CGRectGetWidth(dstRect), CGRectGetHeight(dstRect)));
    CGRect interiorRect = CGRectInset(dstRect, radius, radius);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(dstRect.size);
    CGContextRef maskedContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(maskedContextRef);

    CGMutablePathRef borderPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(borderPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(interiorRect), CGRectGetMinY(interiorRect), radius, PNDegreeToRadian(180), PNDegreeToRadian(270), NO);
    CGPathAddArc(borderPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(interiorRect), CGRectGetMinY(interiorRect), radius, PNDegreeToRadian(270.0), PNDegreeToRadian(360.0), NO);
    CGPathAddArc(borderPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(interiorRect), CGRectGetMaxY(interiorRect), radius, PNDegreeToRadian(0.0), PNDegreeToRadian(90.0), NO);
    CGPathAddArc(borderPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(interiorRect), CGRectGetMaxY(interiorRect), radius, PNDegreeToRadian(90.0), PNDegreeToRadian(180.0), NO);

    CGContextBeginPath(maskedContextRef);
    CGContextAddPath(maskedContextRef, borderPath);
    CGContextClosePath(maskedContextRef);
    CGContextClip(maskedContextRef);

    [self drawInRect: dstRect];

    maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextRestoreGState(maskedContextRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return maskedImage;
}
```

and here's the crash log. It looks the same whenever I get one of these crashes

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6e2e6181
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x30fe56d8 CGGStateGetRenderingIntent + 4
1   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x33c4a7d8 ripc_RenderImage + 104
2   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x33c51868 ripc_DrawImage + 3860
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x30fecad4 CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 80
4   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x30feca40 CGContextDrawImage + 368
5   UIKit                           0x30a6a708 -[UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:] + 1460
6   UIKit                           0x30a66904 -[UIImage drawInRect:] + 72
7   MyApp                           0x0003f8a8 -[UIImage(PNAdditions) borderedImageWithRect:radius:] (UIImage+PNAdditions.m:187)
```

Comment: Why do you do CGContextSaveGState() and CGContextRestoreGState()? Reading the documentation, I get the impression that the state is internal to the context, and the entire context gets thrown away anyways.

Comment: Is it necessary to call CGContextBeginPath() and CGContextClosePath() as you do?  I've found that I can just create a path and call CGContextAddPath() and things work fine.  Also, the docs for CGContextClosePath() say that "when you fill or clip an open path, Quartz implicitly closes the subpath for you", suggesting that there is not a need to close it yourself.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Here is an even easier method that is available in iPhone 3.0 and up. Every View-based object has an associated layer. Each layer can have a corner radius set, this will give you just what you want:

```
UIImageView * roundedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.jpg"]];
// Get the Layer of any view
CALayer * l = [roundedView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];

// You can even add a border
[l setBorderWidth:4.0];
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Obviously, this wasn't the answer back when I asked the question (under 2.0), but it seems to be a great answer under the current world order (ie, 3.x). It's got the added benefit of working with any UIView, which is what brought me back here.

Comment: As mentioned below, don't forget to include #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Yay! This is great when you have a UIImageView ... but the question concerns UIImage, no? (If speed is an issue and you don't want to be allocating UIImageView objects, that is.)

Comment: Just a note to anyone who hits the same problem I had - you must set the image of the image view BEFORE rounding the corners.

Comment: The question was "Rounded Corners on UIImage" (not uiimageview) so preferrably the answer should be too.

Comment: hah! funny that I didn't even add QuartzCore.framework to my project and this works like a charm in iOS 7. Do I have the framework somewhere else rather than Link Binary With Libraries!?

Answer (score 29):

I'm gonna go ahead here and actually answer the question in the title.

Try this category.

**UIImage+additions.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (additions)
-(UIImage*)makeRoundCornersWithRadius:(const CGFloat)RADIUS;
@end
```

**UIImage+additions.m**

```
#import "UIImage+additions.h"

@implementation UIImage (additions)
-(UIImage*)makeRoundCornersWithRadius:(const CGFloat)RADIUS {
    UIImage *image = self;

    // Begin a new image that will be the new image with the rounded corners
    // (here with the size of an UIImageView)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);

    const CGRect RECT = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    // Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:RECT cornerRadius:RADIUS] addClip];
    // Draw your image
    [image drawInRect:RECT];

    // Get the image, here setting the UIImageView image
    //imageView.image
    UIImage* imageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Lets forget about that we were drawing
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageNew;
}
@end
```

Comment: It befuddles me that this question gets so many hits to this day. It also befuddles me to think that we didn't have things like UIBezierPath when I asked the question (iOS 2.0). Man, we've come a long way.

Comment: @Jablair - Well, as of Apple deciding contact images need to be in a circular views in iOS 7, we now need a lot of circular UIImages.

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer, all the other answers are wrong if UIImageView doesn't use the UIViewContentModeScaleToFill content mode. This works correctly with any content mode.

Answer (score 22):

If appIconImage is an UIImageView, then:

```
appIconImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"]; 
appIconImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
appIconImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
appIconImage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
appIconImage.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
```

And also remember:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

I cant offer any insight into your crash, but I thought I would offer another option for rounding the corners.  I had a similar problem arise in an application i was working on.  Rather than write any code I am overlaying another image which masks off the corners.

Comment: I tried masking with an image and was never able to get it to work reliably / at all. Do you have any pointers at how you got it to work?

It was a while ago, so I don't exactly remember what I tried, but I think I went through CGImageCreateWithMask, CGImageMaskCreate, and CGContextClipToMask.

Comment: I am not masking in code.  I am simply drawing another UIImage over top of the image i want to mask.  The UIImage has a transparent section in the middle and black (my background color) edges that i want to "mask off".

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling your method (borderedImageWithRect) in a background thread, crashes might occur since UIGraphics-functions are not thread-safe. In such a case, you must create a context using CGBitmapContextCreate() - see the "Reflection" sample code from the SDK.

Comment: fjoachim, have you actually done this? I'm having a problem drawing to a bitmap context on a background thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702914/using-core-graphics-cocoa-can-you-draw-to-a-bitmap-context-from-a-background-th

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to embed a disabled[!] round-rect [not custom!] button in your view (can even do it all in the Interface Builder) and associate your image with it. The image-setting message is different for UIButton (compared to UIImageView), but the overall kludge works like a charm. Use setImage:forState: if you want a centered icon or setBackgroundImage:forState: if you want the whole image with corners cut (like Contacts). Of course if you want to display lots of these images in your drawRect this isn't the right approach, but more likely an embedded view is exactly what you needed anyway...

Answer (score 2):

I would reiterate [fjoachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205431/rounded-corners-on-uiimage/452643#452643): be cautious when attempting to draw while running on a separate thread, or you may get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.

My workaround went something like this:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OriginalImage.png"] 
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImageWithRoundedCorners:) withObject:originalImage waitUntilDone:YES];
```

(In my case I was resizing / scaling UIImages.)

Answer (score 2):

I actually had a chance to talk about this with somebody from Apple at the iPhone Tech Talk in New York. When we talked about it, he was pretty sure it wasn't a threading issued. Instead, he thought that I needed to retain the graphics context that was generated when calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. This seems to violate the general rules dealing with retain rules and naming schemes, but this fellow was pretty sure he'd seen the issue previously.

If the memory was getting scribbled, perhaps by another thread, that would certainly explain why I was only seeing the issue occasionally.

I haven't had time to revisit the code and test out the fix, but PCheese's comment made me realize I hadn't posted the info here.

...unless I wrote that down wrong and `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` should've been `CGBitmapContextCreate`...

Answer (score 1):

If it only crashes some of the time, figure out what the crash cases have in common.  Is dstRect the same every time?  Are the images ever a different size?

Also, you need to `CGPathRelease(borderPath)`, although I doubt that leak is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the release reminder. I'd accidentally commented that out with some other debugging code, which I then trimmed before posting.

dstRect is the same, but the images could be different because they're downloaded from the web. I'm getting these from a tester - I haven't repro'd this myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OriginalImage.png"] 
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImageWithRoundedCorners:) withObject:originalImage waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

```
let imgView = UIImageView()
imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200)
imgView.image = UIImage(named: "yourimagename")
imgView.imgViewCorners()
//If you want complete round shape
//imgView.imgViewCorners(width: imgView.frame.width)//Pass ImageView width
view.addSubview(imgView)

extension UIImageView {
//If you want only round corners
func imgViewCorners() {
    layer.cornerRadius = 10
    layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}
//If you want complete round shape
func imgViewCorners(width:CGFloat) {
    layer.cornerRadius = width/2
    layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the Image in xib or storyboard (image width and height 41x41).

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface....

IBOutlet UIImageView *testImg;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
        testImg.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        testImg.layer.cornerRadius=20;
        testImg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }
```