# Clipping multiple paths out of UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

In my drawRect method I draw a UIImage, eg

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"shape.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(50,50,50,50)];
```

I want to be able to clip multiple shapes out of the shape so the background of the view is shown. I can't seem to get the quartz clipping methods to behave as I want.

Can anyone help push me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are wanting is to create a mask and apply that to a `UIImage`.  Take a look here: [Rounded corners question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262156/uiimage-rounded-corners/262566#262566).