# UIImage in a circle

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

Can somebody help me here?. New as iPhone Developer. I am trying to display a .png picture in a circle instead of a rectangle which is the standard for iPhone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21329347/501487

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399343/making-a-uiimage-to-a-circle-form/21954535#21954535

Answer (score 52):

Well, all png files are 'rectangles' but if you want to have the apperence of a circle or other non rectangle object on the screen you can do so by using transparacy.  To make sure the transparent pixels in the image are also transparent on the iPhone, you can set the background color of the UIImageView to clear.  This can be done in Interface Builder by dragging the opacity slider in the background color picker all the way down,
or in code as follows:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourRoundImage.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

If you simply want to add rounder corners, to make a circle, you can also use the cornerRadius Property like this if you have added the QuartzCore framework to your project:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourRoundImage.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width / 2;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

Comment: A solution which works fine! However if you have a lot of image

Comment: The cornerRadius line should be `imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;`

Answer (score 30):

try this code

```
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

this show image like ios 7 circle image thanks

Comment: this was a perfect solution!

Answer (score 17):

My contribution with a swift extension used to set an UIImageView as circle

```
extension UIImageView{

    func asCircle(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Just call `MyImageView.asCircle()`

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented the exact same solution in my code, except that I've made an extension of UIView, as I can call the same method even for other objects (like buttons...).

Comment: Where do you store your extension, what type of file do you create and what folder do put it in terms of MVC?

Comment: @YashJain, I create a .swift file and store all my extensions there

Answer (score 9):

Use a UIImageView and set the cornerRadius to be half height and width.  view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;

[UIImage rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262156/uiimage-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 4):

Try this to get rounded corners of the image View and also to colour the corners:

```
self.imgView.layer.cornerRadius =self.imgView.frame.size.height/2;
self.imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:148/255. green:79/255. blue:216/255. alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.imgView.layer.borderWidth=2;
```

Condition*: The height and the width of the imageView must be same to get rounded corners.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the cornerRadius of the image view works well if you have only a couple of images in your view. However if the image view is in a tableview performance will be affected.

Some of the other options:

1. Make the image assets circle on the server or manually if they are bundled into the app, with transparent parts for the outer region of the circle.
2. If the background of the image view doesn't change, create an overlay image that has the inner circle part transparent, and the rest to be the same as the background. Also set the backgroundColor of the image view to clearColor.
3. When receiving the images, edit them in code to be a circle, in a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:** This should display your .png in a circle.

1. Drag (ctrl + click) an `IBOutlet` of an image toward your code.

[image]

cornerRadius
The radius to use when drawing rounded corners for the layer’s background. Animatable. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius

clipsToBounds property
A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the bounds of the view. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds

2.Inside viewDidLoad(), **Use the instance property `layer.cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds`.**

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 50
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a slightly more universal extension to `UIImageView` that will work with non-square images.
To be noted that it will work slower than the `cornerRadius` method.

```
extension UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable public var asEllipse:Bool {
        get {
            if let mask = self.layer.mask {
                return mask.name == kMaskLayerName
            }
            return false;
        }

        set {
            if (newValue) {
                let ellipseMask = CAShapeLayer()
                ellipseMask.name = kMaskLayerName
                ellipseMask.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(self.bounds, nil)
                ellipseMask.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
                ellipseMask.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                self.layer.mask = ellipseMask
            } else if self.asEllipse {
                self.layer.mask = nil
            }
        }
    }

}

private let kMaskLayerName="EllipseMaskLayer"
```

Comment: Why is this slower than `cornerRadius`?

Comment: I would guess it's the object allocations that slow it down: one `CAShapeLayer`, one `CGPath` and two `UIColor` instances. Although having tested that for cell images in a `tableView` on an iPhone 5 and upwards there is no noticeable slowdown when scrolling. TBH I haven't done a proper optimization investigation in Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

On Objective-C it looks like:

```
UIImage* pIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];
UIImageView* pIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pIconImage];
[pIconView.layer setCornerRadius:pIconImage.size.width / 2];
[pIconView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```