# Crop image in star shape iphone

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing, core-graphics, crop

I have a image in rectangle shape but i want to crop this image in a star shape in my iphone application. so please can any one suggest how i do this? plz suggest. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [comment to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262156/uiimage-rounded-corners/698800#698800) on how to mask an image. The magical part is `CGContextClipToMask`.