# How to put an image in a custom path

Tags: ios, iphone, path, uiimageview, uiimage

I am very new in ios programming and here's my problem. I create a path with CGContext (an hexagon) and I want to put an image into this path. Here's the creation path code:

```
-(void)drawAllShapes:(float)xcoord :(float)ycoord :(float)cote  :(CGContextRef)c :(CGFloat *) fillcolor inRect:(CGRect)rect{

xcoord = xcoord*rect.size.width;
ycoord = ycoord*rect.size.height;
cote = cote*rect.size.height;

float x = 0.1835f*rect.size.width;
float y = 0.06162f*rect.size.height;

CGFloat strokecolor[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, strokecolor);
CGContextSetFillColor(c, fillcolor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 4.0f);
CGContextBeginPath(c);
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, xcoord, ycoord);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord+x, ycoord+y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord+x, ycoord+cote+y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord, ycoord+cote+2*y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord-x, ycoord+cote+y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, xcoord-x, ycoord+y);
CGContextClosePath(c);
CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);    
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Its pretty unclear what you want to achieve? Do you want to draw an image to the screen? or do you want to draw your shapes to an image file?

Comment: I want to display an hexagon with an image inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add a few things here:

Create properties:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPathRef yourPath;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
```

In your draw method, comment out the following lines:

```
//CGContextSetFillColor(c, fillcolor);
//CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);
//CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 4.0f);
```

After you close your path, add the following:

```
CGContextClosePath(c);

self.yourPath = CGContextCopyPath(c);

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.bounds = (CGRect){<Specify_Rect>};
shapeLayer.path = self.yourPath;

self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<Your_Image>"]];
self.imageView.layer.frame = (CGRect){<Specify_Rect>}; //Minor correction: changed to frame.
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;

[self addSubview:self.imageView];
CGPathRelease(self.path);
CGContextRelease(c);
```

You should be able to see your image being "wrapped" by your path. I tested it before posting here; have a great time with it, enjoy.

Comment: One last question : how can I change the image position within the path?

Comment: @user3225023 You can use: `self.imageview.layer.position = (CGPoint){<Points>};`

Comment: self.imageview.layer.position changes the "block" position (block = hexagon+image). I want that the hexagon stay at the same position and that I can change the position of the image inside.

Comment: @user3225023 Then use this instead: `shapeLayer.position = (CGPoint){<Points>};`

Answer (score 0):

In a place where you have a valid `CGContext` write:

```
UIImage * image = ...;
float x = 10;
float y = 10;
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

If you want to scale the image or stretch it, use different values for `image.size.width`and `image.size.height`

The x and y is the location where you want it to be drawn.

Comment: I tried your method but the image is over the hexagon. But I want to crop the image by the hexagon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you want to use *CGContext* for this purpose? Here is another way:

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage: (UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

This function takes an **image**, that you want to mask, and a **mask**, which will be applied to the initial image and returns exactly **what you want**. You just need to add proper hexagon image to your project.

Besides it, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262156/uiimage-rounded-corners/).

Comment: Ok but how can I convert my CGContext hexagon to an UIImage?

Comment: Added a link to a similar question.