# SwiftUI TabView: .tabItem with custom image does not show

Tags: swiftui

I have a `TabView` that shall show a `.tabItem` with a custom image (not an `Image(systemName:)`):

```
@ObservedObject var model: MaintainAreaSelectionModel = MaintainAreaSelectionModel()


... 

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Image("Timeline")

            TabView(selection: $model.lastSelectedMaintainAreaIndex) {

                SomeView()
                    .tabItem({

                            Image("Timeline")
                            Text("Title")
                    })
                    .tag(0)
            }
        }
    }
...
```

While the first `Image` shows the icon correctly, the second `Image` just shows a gray circle.

The image is part of the `Assets` catalog, I tried it with PDF vector images as well as with dedicated Bitmaps for all sizes (according to Apple's HIG) - no difference, always gray.

Any idea what's happening here? Are there perhaps any undocumented constraints that the image must fulfill to work as `tabItem`?

Answer (score 4):

I found that I can display a custom image in a tab item with SwiftUI, but only if the source is a `UIImage` and the modifiers must be set on the `UIImage`, as they have no effect when applied to the SwiftUI `Image` constructed from `UIImage`.

This is the component that I'm using to display a rounded fixed sized image on the tab tray. It resizes the supplied `UIImage`, clips it with a circle and the sets the rendering mode to original, otherwise it's just grey.

```swift
struct TabIcon: View {
    var icon: UIImage
    var size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

    // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32303467
    var roundedIcon: UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: self.size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 1)
        defer {
            // End context after returning to avoid memory leak
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rect,
            cornerRadius: self.size.height
            ).addClip()
        icon.draw(in: rect)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: roundedIcon.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TabView` Images have to be a very specific size/format for them to work

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/navigation-and-search/tab-bars/

If you download the SF Symbols app from the Apple Website you can export a template so you can create your own symbol that behaves just like the

```
Image(systemName: "")
```

`Image`. Just open the SF symbols app click on an image that resembles your image (for visual reference) the go to `File>Export Symbol` you can them mimic the image.

Once you edit the exported svg to match your specifications you can just drag it into assets.

Then you can use `Image("yourSVGfilename")`

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you have to set Image to render as `Original Image` from `Assets`.

[image]

Then set `renderMode` in tabbar Image as a `.original`

```
TabView(selection: $model.lastSelectedMaintainAreaIndex) {

            SomeView()
                .tabItem({

                        Image("Timeline").renderingMode(.original)
                        Text("Title")
                })
                .tag(0)
        }
```

Comment: It can load but cannot resize

Comment: Is it possible to resize it?

Comment: @SharkDeng ```.resizable().frame(width: 100, height:100)```