# Debugging NSoperation BAD ACCESS within graphics context

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried everything to debug this one but I can't get to the bottom of it.

This code lives in a subclass of NSOperation which is processed from a queue:

(borders is an ivar NSArray containing 5 UIimage objects)

---

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {       

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGPoint thumbPoint = CGPointMake(6, 6);

    [controller.image drawAtPoint:thumbPoint];

    CGPoint borderPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [[borders objectAtIndex:i] drawAtPoint:borderPoint];

    [images addObject:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}

[images release];
```

---

The code works fine most of the time but when I push the iphone by access subviews and pressing lots of buttons on the UI I either get this exception which is trapped by the operation:

```
Exception Load view: *** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil
```

or I get this:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

The exception is caused because UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() return nil.

I don't know how to debug the EXC_BAD_ACCESS but I'm guessing that this error (in fact both of these errors) is caused by low memory.  The debugger stops at the line:

```
    [controller.image drawAtPoint:thumbPoint];
```

As I mentioned I've trapped the exception so I can live with that but the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is more serious.

IF this is memory related how can I tell and is it possible to increase the memory available to NSOperation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the NSOperationQueue being processed on the main thread or a background thread? If the latter you will not be able to do any graphics context stuff (or sometimes you will sometimes you won't).

Comment: It's on a background thread (well the queue is processed on the main thread but the operation runs in the background) , the code works 90% of the time, its only when I start hammering the UI that it fails. Why shouldn't I be able to do graphics context stuff on the backround thread?

Comment: CoreGraphics calls are generally ok, but UI calls (such as `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`) are usually only callable from the main thread. I don't the finer details, but you might fine some more info here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13963-background-threads-graphics.html

Comment: If you can recast your code using `CGBitmapContext` you'll probably solve your problem.

Comment: You might also find a question I asked here a year ago relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702914/using-core-graphics-cocoa-can-you-draw-to-a-bitmap-context-from-a-background-th

Comment: Phil you are a genius, I've spent hours on this with no luck but using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext seems to work!  More testing to do but thanks again for your help.

Comment: Did you mean, `CGBitmapContext`? You were already using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Either way - glad I could help :-)