# First and Last cell's round corner of UITableViewCell grouped table

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I made custom uiTableViewCell and used it UITableview like screen shot.
Problem is first and last cell's round corner on the groupd table. 
[image]

How to make fist and last cell round corner

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)

Comment: Please do a thorough search on StackOverflow before posting queries. There are so many questions like this.

Comment: I have read it , but I don't solve it for my problem which happens from UITableViewCell and groups table.

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122657/uitableviewcell-has-square-corner-with-image

Answer (score 3):

Add tableView as a property to your cell, and set it in your controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableView *tableView;
```

Then you can implement it like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIRectCorner rectCorner;
    BOOL roundCorners = YES;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:self];
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

    if (numberOfRows == 1) { // single cell
        rectCorner = UIRectCornerAllCorners;
    } else if (indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1) { // bottom cell
        rectCorner = UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
    } if (indexPath.row == 0) { // top cell
        rectCorner = UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;
    } else {
        roundCorners = NO;
    }

    if (roundCorners) {

        CGFloat cornerRadius = 10.0;
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                                       byRoundingCorners:rectCorner
                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
}
```

You could avoid having `tableView` on a property by checking for `self.superview.superview` (iOS7, `self.superview` before), but I think it's a cleaner and less error-prone way.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Look at this sample project on [this link!](http://www.hanspinckaers.com/reproducing-a-tableview-like-in-stocks-spotlight-weather) .

Comment: This rounds all corners of the view, while only one has to be rounded

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background color of the cells clearColor: Your table seems to have rounded corners, but your cells are overriding it. Another alternative solution might be to change the properties of the view behind the table. Try:

```
backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

or

```
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

You may need to

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```