# UIView with rounded corners: how to clip subviews correctly?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, quartz-graphics

I created a subclass of `UIView` that overrides `drawRect:` and uses `AddArcToPoint()` to draw rounded corners. (I don't want to use the layer's corner radius property because I need to define which corners have to be rounded.)
The problem I cannot get over however: if I add a subview at (0|0), it hides my round corners. Any idea how I can fix this? I would like it to clip nicely.

Here's the code that draws the round cornered rectangle. It's Monotouch but should be readably by any developer.

(you can find the full code here: https://github.com/Krumelur/RoundedRectView)

```
public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
        {
            using (var oContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
            {
                oContext.SetLineWidth (this.StrokeWidth);
                oContext.SetStrokeColor (this.oStrokeColor.CGColor);
                oContext.SetFillColor (this.oRectColor.CGColor);

                RectangleF oRect = this.Bounds;

                float fRadius = this.CornerRadius;
                float fWidth = oRect.Width;
                float fHeight = oRect.Height;

                // Make sure corner radius isn't larger than half the shorter side.
                if (fRadius > fWidth / 2.0f)
                {
                    fRadius = fWidth / 2.0f;
                }
                if (fRadius > fHeight / 2.0f)
                {
                    fRadius = fHeight / 2.0f;    
                }

                float fMinX = oRect.GetMinX ();
                float fMidX = oRect.GetMidX ();
                float fMaxX = oRect.GetMaxX ();
                float fMinY = oRect.GetMinY ();
                float fMidY = oRect.GetMidY ();
                float fMaxY = oRect.GetMaxY ();

                // Move to left middle.
                oContext.MoveTo (fMinX, fMidY);

                // Arc to top middle.
                oContext.AddArcToPoint (fMinX, fMinY, fMidX, fMinY, (this.RoundCorners & ROUND_CORNERS.TopLeft) == ROUND_CORNERS.TopLeft ? fRadius : 0);
                // Arc to right middle.
                oContext.AddArcToPoint (fMaxX, fMinY, fMaxX, fMidY, (this.RoundCorners & ROUND_CORNERS.TopRight) == ROUND_CORNERS.TopRight ? fRadius : 0);
                // Arc to bottom middle.
                oContext.AddArcToPoint (fMaxX, fMaxY, fMidX, fMaxY, (this.RoundCorners & ROUND_CORNERS.BottomRight) == ROUND_CORNERS.BottomRight ? fRadius : 0);
                // Arc to left middle.
                oContext.AddArcToPoint (fMinX, fMaxY, fMinX, fMidY, (this.RoundCorners & ROUND_CORNERS.BottomLeft) == ROUND_CORNERS.BottomLeft ? fRadius : 0);

                // Draw the path.
                oContext.ClosePath ();
                oContext.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a piece of code that demonstrates how to solve it using CALayer.

```
private void UpdateMask()
        {
            UIBezierPath oMaskPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect (this.Bounds, this.eRoundedCorners, new SizeF (this.fCornerRadius, this.fCornerRadius));

            CAShapeLayer oMaskLayer = new CAShapeLayer ();
            oMaskLayer.Frame = this.Bounds;
            oMaskLayer.Path = oMaskPath.CGPath;
            this.Layer.Mask = oMaskLayer;
        }
```

Comment: Any way to add borders to the rounded view?

Comment: Sure. In DrawLayer add a CGPath.FromRoundedRect() and use a thing black stroke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I think you could use CALayer's mask property to do this. You'd have to draw your rounded rectangle into a layer that was set as the mask to your view layer.

Comment: That was a brilliant hint! I will update the code on https://github.com/Krumelur/RoundedRectView to use as CALayer mask. It is a one liner!

Comment: The code to do this in Objective-C is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10515546/197626

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (and, in fact, very easy) to specify particular rounded corners without resorting to `drawRect:`, or manually drawing a partially rounded rect into a layer. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how/5826698#5826698) on a similar question.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found and used after getting the CALayer hint. Thanks! My only issue with it is auto resizing. CALayer does not auto resize. So I override frame and bounds and update the mask but this cannot be animated and if you rotate the device, it looks a bit chunky.