# Return UIImageView from this code?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgcontext, rounding

I have found the following code from this link: iphone - How to draw a rounded rectangle in Core Graphics / Quartz 2D? - Stack Overflow

So pretty much this is the code:

```
- (UIImageView*)roundImageView:(CGFloat)rad {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 

    CGRect rrect = ivprofilePicture.bounds;

    CGFloat radius = rad; 

    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect), midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect); 

    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect), midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect); 

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy); 

    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius); 

    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius); 

    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius); 

    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius); 

    CGContextClosePath(context); 

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);



    UIImageView *imageView;

    return imageView;

}
```

I would then call it like this:

```
myImageView = [self roundImageView:10];
```

The problem is, how would I return a UIImageView from this code? I have already created a method that takes in a radius parameter and returns an UIImageView. The rect in the code above is already set to original UIImageView's bounds too.

However, I just have no idea how I would return the UIImageView with its rounded corners from this code.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you begin an image context, and have drawn something on it, I think it would be similar to how you would take a screenshot from the current screen?

```
UIImage* imageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then just return a new UIImageView with `initWithImage` as per normal. However, I don't see there is a need to create a new UIImageView every time you draw the image. You can return `UIImage*` instead and recycle the UIImageView.

Comment: Where would I put that code in relation to the code I posted?

Comment: @iBradApps: Add it to the end of your code, before the return statement.

Comment: That's a UIImage, not a UIImageView. So then after that, do this: `UIImageView* ret = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease]; return ret;`, assuming you rename the UIImage variable to "image".

Answer (score 0):

[Add rounded corners to all UIImageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171506/add-rounded-corners-to-uiimageview)

[UIImage rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262156/uiimage-rounded-corners)

Here are some links that I think are related to your question.

Comment: I cannot do either. I must use Core Graphics because the other 2 ways are slowing down my app.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the UIImageView, try doing this:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init /*or whatever other init method*/] autorelease];
return imageView;
```

Comment: No, I must get a UIImageView from the CGContext.