# How to show specific area in UIImageView from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

If I have a image size 1024*768, but I want to show a 100*100 square located on 200, 200. What is the simplest way to do it? Thz u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically talking about a "Crop" operation.

From [HitScan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9490/hitscan) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage):

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
// or use the UIImage wherever you like
[UIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```