# Does ARC work with Core Graphics objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

I recently started a new project using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).
When I assigned the contents of a CALayer:

```
UIView* view = ...
UIImage* image = ...
view.layer.contents = image.CGImage
```

I got an error

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'CGImageRef' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Simply casting the `CGImageRef` to `id` hides the error, but I was wondering if the ARC still functions correctly then?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should really check out the ARC videos from WWDC 2011. They are available on the developer site and open through iTunes. Especially:

> • Session 323 – Introducing Automatic Reference Counting
>
> • Session 322 – Objective-C Advancements in Depth

Also, the ARC reference notes:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Both the reference notes and the videos discuss Core Graphics (et al) and how they work with ARC.

Specifically, look at the section called **"Managing Toll-Free Bridging"**

> In many Cocoa applications, you need to use Core Foundation-style objects, whether from the Core Foundation framework itself (such as
> CFArrayRef or CFMutableDictionaryRef) or from frameworks that adopt
> Core Foundation conventions such as Core Graphics (you might use types
> like CGColorSpaceRef and CGGradientRef).
>
> The compiler does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core
> Foundation objects; you must call CFRetain and CFRelease (or the
> corresponding type-specific variants) as dictated by the Core
> Foundation memory management rules (see Memory Management Programming
> Guide for Core Foundation).
>
> If you cast between Objective-C and Core Foundation-style objects, you
> need to tell the compiler about the ownership semantics of the object
> using either a cast (defined in objc/runtime.h) or a Core
> Foundation-style macro (defined in NSObject.h): [...]

Jörg Jacobsen has a good summary overview of the bridging options as well: [Managing Toll-free Bridging in an ARC’ed Environment](http://www.joergjacobsen.com/blog/2011/10/05/managing-toll-free-bridging-in-an-arced-environment/).

> **__bridge_retained** (n.b.: only use it when casting from object pointer to C type pointer): I (the programmer) need to reference this object
> for some time in the dark world of C type pointers which is opaque to
> you, ARC. So please, please do not release this object while I still
> need it. I (the programmer) promise to release it myself (in the dark
> world) when I’m done with it
>
> **__bridge_transfer** (n.b.: only use it when casting from C type pointer to object pointer): I (the programmer) hand over to you, ARC, an
> object that I own and that I am no longer interested in in the dark
> world of C type pointers that is opaque to you. Whenever you, ARC, are
> done with that object please release it yourself, because you know the
> right time and thus save me some work not having to do it myself.
>
> **__bridge**: ARC, you keep balancing out your retains and releases as I keep balancing out mine in the dark world of C type pointers which
> is…. Whenever I need to hold on to an object in the dark world I will
> retain it myself and release it when appropriate. I don’t need any
> extra contract with you, ARC.

Comment: :) Thanks! Glad I could help! We migrated a fairly large app we have a couple days ago and it took about two days to work all the kinks out, but I'm pretty pleased with the end result. A lot less code, a lot more robust. ARC is pretty cool. Those videos were an awesome resource for me.

Answer (score 8):

Despite the references pointed out by Steve, I believe the case you show above might be special.  From the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), pay attention to the section "The Compiler Handles CF Objects Returned From Cocoa Methods":

> The compiler understands Objective-C methods that return Core
>   Foundation types follow the historical Cocoa naming conventions (see
>   Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide). For example, the
>   compiler knows that, in iOS, the CGColor returned by the CGColor
>   method of UIColor is not owned.

The code example they provide:

```
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor],
                                                 (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor], nil];
```

relies on the known return of CGColors from these methods (they are missing the cast to id that I've added in the above code, which should be corrected in their documentation soon).

Because `[image CGImage]` follows the naming conventions, I believe the CGImage will be bridged properly here.  I think that your cast to id should be all that you need here.

Answer (score 4):

One popular answer to `layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage` question is `layer.contents = obj_unretainedObject(image.CGImage)`.

I do `=(__bridge id)image.CGImage`.

Comment: I recommend adding code formatting to your answer, to improve readability.