# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() crashes the app on iPad 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

My problem  is when I assign the image which was returned by the UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() , to the UIImageView more than once, my app crashes.  Here is my code: If omit the assignment line of UIImageView app will not crash.

```
 UIImage *   newImage3;  
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(duplicateImage.size);

            [duplicateImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];


            context2=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            for(int k=0; k<kmtaGroup->TotalLines; k++)
            {
                lineObject=&kmtaGroup->Line_INFO_OBJ[k];
                x0 = lineObject->x0;
                y0= lineObject->y0;
                x1= lineObject->x1;
                y1= lineObject->y1;
                color= lineObject->Color;
                lineWidth= lineObject->LinkWidth;

                lineColor=[self add_colorWithRGBAHexValue:color];
                linearColor=lineColor;

                // Brush width
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context2, lineWidth);
                // Line Color
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context2,[linearColor CGColor]);


                CGContextMoveToPoint(context2, x0, y0);

                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context2, x1, y1);
                CGContextStrokePath(context2);


            }



             newImage3=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        }

              imageView.image=newImage3;

             UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Will please share code ? and OS version running on iPad3

Comment: please post your code and crash logs

Comment: @Jageen  posted the code.

Comment: @SeanChense how can I get the crash logs and post here ?

Comment: @Jageen , I have noticed one thing , that is If I perform this task with delay of few seconds then app doesn't crash immediately , though it gives memory warning repeatedly

Comment: @Farrukh it may be memory leak did you try this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121120/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext-memory-leak-pdf-previews

Comment: @Farrukh i think same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578934/memory-warning-and-crash-arc-how-to-identify-why-its-happening

Comment: How many lines are you drawing in that loop?

Comment: @Jageen yes I  have been through from these two posts .. but did't work for me ... tried different solutions as suggested by the experts on this these posts.

Comment: @LyndseyScott it depends upon the touched location. sometimes i have to draw one line and  some time I draw 60 lines....

Comment: @LyndseyScott but I don't think so its an issue of drawing lines.

Comment: @Farrukh please check this demo i tried with your code, i could not reproduce memory warning or crash https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KnvB_2930aZnJmTVhyREtXdjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jageen ok , let me check.

Comment: @Jageen did you try this code on the device ? because in my case my app goes fine in the simulator but on device it crashes

Comment: @Jageen thanks for your efforts. I have run your code on device also ... it doesn't crash. in my case images are very high in resolution e.g. 7000X4000. but you are not using any image. similarly you have just created a demo project and I am running the complete application. so help me to understand this issue with some other way.

Comment: @Farrukh will you share that image ? or create sample code like me which reproduce crash

Comment: @Jageen Well I can't share the image, because in my app I am creating the image from the data and that data is placed on the server...and I have posted my code already. In my near nothing is wrong with the code.

Comment: @Jageen problem is related to UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() returned image.

Comment: @Jageen or it could be an issue of multiple calling of this method in my app. because it gives me memory warning on the second call .  and then crash occurs.

Comment: @Farrukh OK i will try to reproduce it, but it did not crash even if i click many time on "button" in my demo application.

Comment: @Jageen you are right. your demo app doesn't crash, no matter how many times you call the method.

Comment: @Jageen another important behaviour which I observed now that is , if image is zoomed in then it doesn't give me any memory warning and app goes fine superbly... I fail to understand what's going on ...  :(    No matter how many times I call the method.

Comment: @Jageen when I get memory warning it gives me statement on app crash "Terminating in response to backboard's termination" .