# UIImagePickerController crashes the app after 50-60 images

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing a serious issue with UIImagePickerController in swift. After capturing 50-60 images continuously, the app crashed without logging any issue in fabric crashlytics. It seems to be a memory issue.
I have tried the following solution.

```
@interface UIImagePickerController (Singleton)
   +(UIImagePickerController *) instance;
@end

@implementation UIImagePickerController (Singleton)
  +(UIImagePickerController *) instance{
   static UIImagePickerController *_instance;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{
     _instance=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   });
   return _instance
  }

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
    let image = UIImagePickerController.instance() //Singleton call used here
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    image.allowEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(image,animated: true,completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
    autoreleasepool{
      var image: UIImage? =info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
      imageView.image = Utils.resizeAndCompress(image)
      image=nil
   } 
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion: nil)
}
```

Any idea what's wrong here? Your help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

```
class func resizeAndCompress(image: UIImage!) -> UIImage? {

    let size = image.size
    let maxLength: CGFloat = 640.0

    var newSize: CGSize
    if size.width > size.height {
        let scale = maxLength / size.width
        newSize = CGSizeMake(maxLength, size.height * scale)
    } else {
        let scale = maxLength / size.height
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * scale, maxLength)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resizedImage

}
```

**Solution for crashing**
It appears the Issue is with the iOS version. I have created my custom image picker control using AVVideoCapture. Now I am able to capture more than 1000 images.

Comment: put a breakpoint in didReceiveMemoryWarning method and see if it gets hit during the crash. If not, then it is not a memory issue.

Comment: What is the size of image returned by resizeAndCompress?

Comment: `image=nil` is one curious bit in your delegate method. Are you sure you are not storing images in memory? Also, why do you need the singleton pattern here?

Comment: It looks like he's trying to store way to much in the cache to me.

Comment: @teja-nandamuri, yes it hit the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Comment: @NSNoob I have implemented singleton pattern due to suggestion on stackoverflow on other posts. But the error is there with singleton or without singleton pattern

Comment: @Sethmr Can you please explain how it's storing in cache?

Comment: Can you show the method resizeAndCompress ?

Comment: @user2842495 Okay. It appears however that somehow the selected images remain your memory. This can cause crashes due to low memory because images take a lot of toll. Can you add the method requested by Teja so that we can see if you are retaining images somewhere or not?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri,NSNoob I have updated the question description. Please check

Comment: please refer to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578934/memory-warning-and-crash-arc-how-to-identify-why-its-happening  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860215/resizing-a-uiimage-without-loading-it-entirely-into-memory

Comment: Can you post your complete UIImagePickerController implementation?

Comment: I don't know much about how the cache works honestly, but a couple things about your code just hit me as something that would cause a memory warning possibly. Sorry I am not more help.

Comment: Your imagePicker is storing the images in: `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` You already know this. That is why you force cast it to `UIImage` in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. Get rid of it. You thought you `nil` it out by setting the reference to the image to `nil` but it didn't work. You have to `nil` it in the dictionary. You are storing a strong reference to every image that was ever picked.

Comment: @Brandon How can we set nil in the dictionary. info dictionary is read only.

Comment: I have created a custom Image picker controller using AVVideoCapture. Now i am able to capture more than 1000 images.