# Method returns a Core Foundation object a +1 retain

Tags: iphone, ios

Can anyone tell me what is the problem I am having here?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you compiling an ARC code with ARC turned off?

Comment: Undoubtedly you are creating an image inside of `createCGImage` and then never releasing it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, i have tu ARC.
i'm using imageTemp = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]] autorelease]; but get warning "Object sent -autorelease too many times"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you *might* have ARC enabled, that only covers Cocoa / Objective-C objects. [Core Foundation and Core Graphics API's are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800174/does-arc-work-with-core-graphics-objects) and you still need to eventually explicitly release the memory for any of those objects created as well.

In your code, you are doing a "`createCGIImage:`" without a balanced release.

A release looks like:

```
CGImageRelease(myImageRef)
```

So, to do this right, do something like:

```
CGImageRef myImageRef = [context createCGImage: outputImage fromRect: outputImage.extent];
UIImage * imageTemp = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: myImageRef];
CGImageRelease(myImageRef);
```

Answer (score 1):

ARC is irrelevant as you are dealing with a CoreFoundation object. You need to assign it to a `CGImageRef` variable and then release it with `CFRelease(variableName)`.

i.e.

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:...];
// rest of your code here
CFRelease(cgImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[context createCGImage:fromRect:]` method returns a retained `CGImageRef`. The fix your memory leak, you need to save a reference to that `CGImageRef` and release it, when you're done with it:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extend];
imageTemp = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```