# Testing iOS app with instruments for memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, xcode5

I am using Xcode's Instruments for first time and my app is based on ARC and built for iOS 6.1, but currently re-modified for iOS 7 and works well without crashing. I have run tests on a physical iPhone device also and have seen no problems at all.

Running Instruments keeps giving me the following details, but I have not seen any of my classes or objects apart from Libraries.

Is ARC not taking care of this? Do I need to manually release objects for all memory allocations?

Can someone please help me with what is going on here?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This post may help you: [Does ARC work with Core Graphics objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800174/does-arc-work-with-core-graphics-objects)
Also, you need to be aware of retain loops. one object holds a reference (strong) to another object which also holds a reference to the first object (strong). This is most common in using delegation.