# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect not Cropping Correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm having a hell of a time using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to crop a photo. My app has the user move / enlarge an image till it fills a 316 x 316 view, then I want it to crop off any area outside the box and save the image as a UIImage. I determine the crop origin by taking the absolute value of the x and y imageview origin as that brings me back to 0,0 of the view / box that contains the imageview. Below is the code:

```
    CGRect croppedRect = CGRectMake(fabs(widthDistanceToOrigin), fabs(HeightDistanceToOrigin), 316, 316);
    CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, croppedRect); 
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: croppedImageRef scale: 1 / (imageScale) orientation: image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);
```

This is driving me crazy, I just can't get it to crop the area I want. I've got it to scale correctly, but the problem seems to be with the x and y origin of the crop rect, it's quite a bit off from the area it should be taking (and sometimes I get weird results).

Also, it seems for images taken with the phones camera, I have to multiply everything in my crop rect by 2 for it to be the correct size. Very weird.

So I'm wondering, does anyone know how to fix this, or does anyone possible have a better way of cropping (and please keep in mind that I need to crop an area within my photo). Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your solution in an answer, and accept it once the system allows you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was trying to grab the crop area before I scaled the image. Now have to figure out how to reduce the image before I do "CGImageCreateWithImageInRect".

Answer (score 4):

There are so many posts about this topic with all them having the same exact answer,
to utilize: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect
but none of them fully solve the problem of miss positioning of what is trying to be cropped.

However, only one thread (buried deep deep inside), has a minor detail that everyone else is missing...
[How to crop a UIImageView to a new UIImage in 'aspect fit' mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859717/how-to-crop-a-uiimageview-to-a-new-uiimage-in-aspect-fit-mode/10861443#10861443)

the 'rect' parameter that goes in
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, croppedRect)
needs to represent (taken from) the UIImage, NOT the UIImageView.

this should solve the issue of miss positioning on the coordinate system.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:   (NSDictionary *)info
 {
        oImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSLog(@"Original Image size width: %f x height: %f", oImage.size.width, oImage.size.height);


        // crop image according to what the image picker view is displaying
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 40, 960.0f, 960.0f); // note: 960 x 1280 is what natively comes from capturing and image
        nImage = [BGViewModifiers cropImage:oImage inRect:rect];

        // scale image down for display and creating kombie
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 320.0f);
        nImage = [BGViewModifiers imageFromImage:nImage scaledToSize:size];

        NSLog(@"New Image size width: %f x height: %f", [nImage size].width, [nImage size].height);
 }

 //ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25293588/2298002
 + (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage*)image inRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
    double (^rad)(double) = ^(double deg) {
       return deg / 180.0 * M_PI;
    };

    CGAffineTransform rectTransform;
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
      case UIImageOrientationLeft:
          rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(90)), 0, -image.size.height);
          break;
      case UIImageOrientationRight:
          rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-90)), -image.size.width, 0);
          break;
      case UIImageOrientationDown:
          rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-180)), -image.size.width, -image.size.height);
          break;
      default:
          rectTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  };
  rectTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(rectTransform, image.scale, image.scale);

  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, rectTransform));
  UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);

  return result;
 }

 + (UIImage*)imageFromImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
 {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide more information/answer for this based on my own experience.

From the `UIImage` (and thus the `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect:`) perspective, `(0, 0)` is in the bottom left. When determining the crop square, you can simply calculate the square based on the standard portrait orientation and then use the method in @greenhouse's answer (posted again here for clarity and changed to use `CGFloat` to fix a casting error.

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage*)image toRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat (^rad)(CGFloat) = ^CGFloat(CGFloat deg) {
        return deg / 180.0f * (CGFloat) M_PI;
    };

    // determine the orientation of the image and apply a transformation to the crop rectangle to shift it to the correct position
    CGAffineTransform rectTransform;
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(90)), 0, -image.size.height);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-90)), -image.size.width, 0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-180)), -image.size.width, -image.size.height);
            break;
        default:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    };

    // adjust the transformation scale based on the image scale
    rectTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(rectTransform, image.scale, image.scale);

    // apply the transformation to the rect to create a new, shifted rect
    CGRect transformedCropSquare = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, rectTransform);
    // use the rect to crop the image
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, transformedCropSquare);
    // create a new UIImage and set the scale and orientation appropriately
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    // memory cleanup
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return result;
}
```

This code shifts the crop square so that it is in the correct relative position.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me