# How do I prevent a UIImage from being Moved outside of its UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage, photo

I'm trying to create a photo based app and I want to be able to crop, rotate and move the image thats been taken. I've done those things already but the UIImage created moves around the whole UIViewController and I only want it to be moved around within its UIImageView. Could anyone suggest how I might go about trying this? I've tried a few way already but they don't seemed to have worked. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks!

**Update**

I'm adding in my code to help better explain what I'm trying to do . I'm sorry for not doing this before.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
//the 'image' below is the UIImage, it has already been declared before hand
image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

//layoutOne is my UIView which holds my UIImageView and UIImage. all of those are declared in my .h file.

layoutOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95.0, 107.0, 578, 682)];
theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[layoutOne frame]];
[theImageView setImage:image];
[layoutOne addSubview:theImageView];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[layoutOne addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[layoutOne addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[layoutOne addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];


UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[layoutOne addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

[self.view addSubview:layoutOne];
}
```

I'm using Interface Builder to create my app and I'm also using the newest version of Xcode. Thought I'd also add this incase it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can move the image within the image view. What you can to is to create a UIView as the frame and move the image within the bounds of the frame. Below is the code snippet (iOS 5 with ARC) that I hope it helps.

```
@implementation ImageFrame
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
    CGPoint previousPoint;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    previousPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint movePoint = CGPointMake(location.x - previousPoint.x, location.y - previousPoint.y);
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + movePoint.x, imageView.center.y + movePoint.y);
    imageView.center = newCenter;
    previousPoint = location;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your current setup is, but make sure your UIImageView `clipsToBounds` property is set to `YES.`

If this doesn't answer your question, try checking the answers to [Cropping an UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage), which sounds like it may be describing a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried that but for some reason when I added it in, like this: **[theImageView clipsToBounds:YES];** It comes up with the semantic issue: **Instance method '-clipsToBounds:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**

Comment: Sounds like theImageView is not recognized as an `UIImageView` object. Have you passed the object into a method as an `id` instance? If so, try providing the compiler with the correct type information before sending the clipsToBound: message:  `[(UIImageView *) theImageView clipsToBounds:YES];`

Comment: I think what you said was right, however you mentioned you didn't know my setup. To help, i'll post my method of displaying the UIImageView and hopefully it will clarify I should have done that before really. Sorry about that. I'll add in my code above