# How to scale only specific parts of image in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing

I want to scale the image in iPhone app but not entirely. I just want to scale specific parts like the bottom part or the middle part...How do I do it?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

It sounds like you want to do a form of 9-slice scaling or 3-slice scaling.  Let's say you have the following image:

[image: Original]

and you want to make it look like this:

[image: Scaled]

(the diagonal end pieces do not stretch at all, the top and bottom pieces stretch horizontal, and the left and right pieces stretch vertical)

To do this, use `-stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` in iOS 4.x and earlier, or  `-resizableImageWithCapInsets:` starting with iOS 5.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FancyButton"];
UIImage *myResizableImage = [myImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(21.0, 13.0, 21.0, 13.0)];
[anImageView setImage:myResizableImage]
```

To help visualize the scaling, here is an image showing the above cap insets:

[image: Insets]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to adjust the scale of just a part of a UIImage. I'd approach is slightly differently by creating seperate images from your primary image using [CGImageCreateWithImageInRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) and then scaling the seperate images with the different rates that you require.

See:

- [Cropping a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)
- [CGImage Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html)
- [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html)

Comment: hmm yes, this can be a way of doing...will try out. However can we select particular area and then apply scaling to it? by using some touch event?