# let user crop image in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

Is there a built in function in objective-c to do image cropping like the one in iOS photo gallery? I have tried enabling editing in UIImagePickerController, but it doesn't do the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are quite a few ways to crop images using the Core Graphics functions, the most basic one would be:

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
CGImageRef cropped_img = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(yourUIImage.CGImage, cropRect)
```

Comment: so if I want the user to define the portion of image they want cropped, I suppose I should implement UIGestureRecognizers?

Comment: Yeah, there's a pretty good tutorial here: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Answer (score 0):

This is no built in function. The way to do it would be to take the image an get a frame around the portion of the image you want.

[This question should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

Comment: that's too bad. I was hoping for an easy way out :p Thank you for confirming that.