# Partially Convert the image in to black & white effect

Tags: iphone, ios, cgcontext, uicolor, cgcolor

I have one image to which i want to give effect of black & white but only in some portion.For example.
When the goal balance is at 0 dollars the image is 100% gray. The image colour will increase in the same percentage as the current balance of the savings goal. For example, if the savings total is $15000 but the savings balance is $7500, then only 50% of the image will be in colour and the other 50% will be gray.
I know how to completely convert black & white image but don't know how to partially Convert the image into black & white shade.

Answer (score 5):

Something simple would be to create a copy of the image, crop it based on the percentage, convert that to black and white, and overlay it on the other image

[link for how to crop an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

Comment: Is there any reference link with you?

Comment: @wattson12 thanks but i don't want that half image will b&w n half will not I want that Whole image will have effect of partially black & white.....

Comment: @aakilladhani i dont understand what you mean, how can you have the whole image be partially black and white? you could create a black and white version and overlay it with varying alpha values?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Core Image. Essentially you will use your current image as the input to the core image filter, employ a black and white filter, and control the filter so that the image can go from completely color to completely B&W.

So find the Core Image info on the developer site, and then look at the 100 or so filters Apple provides - I'm pretty sure one of them already does what you want.