# Load UIImage from Image Map

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

I know this sounds like a pretty basic task but I've tried searching and such but with no result

For example here's an example of what I'm attempting to do

Load Image

[image: Image Map]

Into an image map into UIImage

Request image from x,y with a width and height.

eg:

```
-(UIImage *) loadImgFromImageMap:(UIImage *)map withRect:(CGRect)dimensions;
```

just as an example. and if I, for example, pass {64, 0, 64, 64} as the rect then the result would be:

[image: UIImage Result]

Any suggestions? :)

Regards

Tim Ellis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course as soon as you post you find the answer elsewhere...

For those looking I found it here

[Cropping an UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

The code I used is basically the same but I add it to UIImage to make things easy

Here it is for those interested

```
//The .h file
@interface UIImage (crop)
- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect;
@end
```

Main File

```
//The .m file
@implementation UIImage (crop)

- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.scale > 1.0f) {
        rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                          rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                          rect.size.width * self.scale,
                          rect.size.height * self.scale);
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}

@end
```

Calling it very easy now.

Here's a sample :)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgMap.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, 40, 40); //Change this to whatever the frame should be
UIImage *cropped = [image crop:frame];
```