# UI navigation bar custom background iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have customized the UINavigationBar of my app with a texture. Here is my code:

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MYIMAGE.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

The code works but I want to reduce the size of my texture how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you resize or crop the image before you set it as appearance to the `UINavigationBar`. Here are two SO links to do that

[Crop UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

[Resize UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)