# How do I cut a UIImage from a sprite sheet?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimage, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet containing many images. I used [texture packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to create the sprite sheet and it outputs a plist containing each image's dimensions and coordinates. Given this information what steps do I need to take to extract individual UIImages? It seems all the examples I find are in the context of Cocos2d which has it's own data format and helper classes. I am not creating animations or anything fancy nor is this a Cocos2d application. I just need to cut out images.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```