# Size of scaled image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get a size(either width or height) of an scaled image in objective-C? Provide with a sample code. Also, I have tried the following but its not working,

Width : self.object.position.x * scaleFactor;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cropping a UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

Comment: I didn't mean about cropping, I just want to know how we can find width/height for an scaled image?

Comment: Use image.scale and image.size https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_11

Answer (score 2):

`UIImage` has a `size` property, a `CGSize` with `width` and `height`. That's the size. Multiply by the scale if you want pixel dimensions.

```
 CGFloat imageWidth = myImage.size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSStringFromCGSize([image size]);
```