# Set the size of Main View according to its subView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a Main View with frame

0, 60, 768, 1024,

It has many views as subView. First subview is an `UIImageView`. The property associated with ImageView is AspectFit. Now I want to take screenshot of the only part of screen which bounds that of `UIImageView` (There are at least 4-5 Subviews which CAN or can not be above This UIImageView) The standard coding given by iPhone has been used here. The image i get is of Main View. Now to get only screenshot of UIImageView and whatever above is, I need to set the dimension of my main view to envelop only UIImageView.

Suppose The image size is 100,100. When I press button, How should I set the `Bounds/fRAME` OF my mainView? Or In other terms how can I get the frame of `UIImageView` relative to self.view

Comment: Do you mean it's `frame` is (0, 60, 768, 1024) ?

Comment: ah yes its frame. I have fixed it

Comment: How about, instead, take an image of the whole main view, then crop the image?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the frame of main view, try to calculate coordinates of the `UIImageView`.

Assume that frames of your main view and image view are (0, 60, 768, 1024) and (20, 20, 100, 100), respectively.

So frame of your image view with respect to global coordinate system is (20, 80, 100, 100). Just add x, y coordinates of main view to its subviews to achieve this. Then, you may get the screenshot of desired frame.

Comment: UIView implements convertRect:toView and ...fromView:, which is how to implement your idea here, though I don't see how this (or the OP's hypothesis of reframing the superview) can work.

Comment: @danh Infact, my intention was to help in calculating the desired rect for a method like yours. I guess, I should have been more explicit. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to grab the entire view's image, then crop it.  No reframing needed.  Combining best answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage), it might look like this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view croppedBy:(CGRect)rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

For your app, call it like this (assuming we're in a view controller):

```
UIImage *justMyImageView = [self imageWithView:self.view croppedBy:self.myImageView.frame];
```