# Implementation of Image cropper

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, imageview

I create a image cropper in xamarin.forms and it's pretty cool on landscape images but when I try to test it on Portrait image my crop view is go out of the image means if I take screenshot of a phone and I try to crop in my application in that I am getting out of the size image means go out of image bound and I am little confuse about that. If any one have a !dea than please help me. One more thing that I use custom control for crop photo. My crop photo view code is as below.

testCrop.cs

```
        using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ()) 
        {
            context.SetFillColor (UIColor.FromRGB(31, 33, 36).ColorWithAlpha((System.nfloat)0.3).CGColor);
            context.FillRect (rect);

            context.SetFillColor (UIColor.White.CGColor);
            context.FillRect (new CGRect ( new CGPoint(origin.X - BorderWidthConstant, origin.Y - BorderWidthConstant), new CGSize (cropSize.Width + BorderWidthConstant*2, cropSize.Height + BorderWidthConstant*2)));

            context.SetBlendMode (CGBlendMode.Clear);
            UIColor.Clear.SetColor ();

            var path = new CGPath ();
            path.AddRect (new CGRect (origin, cropSize));

            context.AddPath (path);
            context.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Fill);
        }
    }
```

When I use to move crop above method is call.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19465139/8187800) is a workaround.

Comment: Let me try Thanks for concern.

Comment: Hi @ColeXia-MSFT Can possible that code might be in a C# because I use your code but it's not working..