# How to take UIScrollView's zoomScale & contentOffset, and apply to larger image?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm stuck with something I can't figure out...

My app lets the user zoom/pan a thumbnail image, via a UIScrollView. Then it needs to take the changes the user made in the scrollview and apply them to the same image at a much higher resolution (ie. generate a high-res UIImage that looks the same as the zoomed/panned low-res thumbnail the user touched).

I can see that the scrollview has a zoomscale and contentOffset which I can reuse, but I really can't see how to apply this to my UIImage.

All help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zoom scale`,`contentOffset` and `frame` of the `UIScrollView` will present a sub rectangle of the thumbnail.

Rescale that rectangle proportionally against the higher res version of your image.

e.g

Your scroller has bounds of `100px` x `100px`

Your thumbnail is `100px` x `100px` and is zoomed at `4x` with a content offset of `(x:100,y:100)`. You will see a sub rectangle of frame (x:25,y:25,w:25,h:25) against the original thumbnail inside the 100x100 window of the scroller i.e blurry. The width and height comes from the scrollers frame.

Once you flip in a high res image of `1000px` x `1000px` you are going to want to present the same chunk of the image except now you present `(x:250,y:250,w:250,h:250)` by setting the zoom to `0.4`. `contentOffset` remains the same.

Note that the zoom of `1x` and zero offset which would present the whole thumbnail image is a zoom of `0.1x` and zero offset against the higher res.

**BUT**

You are overthinking the issue. Your container `UIImageView` does all the work for you. Once you reach your target zoom point simply load the higher res image into the imageView (`myImageView.image = hiresImage` ) and it will "just work" assuming your contentMode is set to `Scale To Fill` (`UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`) or `Aspect Fill` . The low res image will be replaced by the high res version in exactly the right position.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason i don't just replace the low res image with the high one is because the preparation on the high res image is for printing, not for display -- at the end i need a static UIImage that shows the same as what the user did. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Use what I said in the first part then. Apply the visible rect of the thumbnail to your hires version

Comment: Do you mean still in a UIScrollView, and then somehow ask it to render just its visible part? or don't use scrollview and use drawRect somehow?

Comment: I get your problem now - take the rect you derive from your scroll view and use this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage) to do the crop on your hires image