# Cropping image and center

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift how do you crop an image and put it in the center? I've cropped the image but want to put it in the center:

```
ImgView.image = OrigImage
var masklayer = CAShapeLayer()
masklayer.frame = ImgView.frame
masklayer.path = path.CGPath
masklayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
masklayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
ImgView.layer.mask = masklayer

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ImgView.bounds.size);
   ImgView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
   var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   ImgView.image = image
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: @jhayvi Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To get a centered position for your crop, you can halve the difference of the height and width. Then you can assign the bounds for the new width and height after checking the orientation of the image (which part is longer)

```
func cropToBounds(image: UIImage, width: Double, height: Double) -> UIImage {

    let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage)!

    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

    var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
    var cgwidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(width)
    var cgheight: CGFloat = CGFloat(height)

    // See what size is longer and create the center off of that
    if contextSize.width > contextSize.height {
        posX = ((contextSize.width - contextSize.height) / 2)
        posY = 0
        cgwidth = contextSize.height
        cgheight = contextSize.height
    } else {
        posX = 0
        posY = ((contextSize.height - contextSize.width) / 2)
        cgwidth = contextSize.width
        cgheight = contextSize.width
    }

    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(posX, posY, cgwidth, cgheight)

    // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
    let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(contextImage.CGImage, rect)

    // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)!

    return image
}
```

I found most of this info over at this [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20150809132743/http://carl-thomas.name/crop-image-to-square/) in case you wanted to read further.

Updated for **Swift 4**

```
func cropToBounds(image: UIImage, width: Double, height: Double) -> UIImage {

        let cgimage = image.cgImage!
        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)
        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size
        var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
        var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
        var cgwidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(width)
        var cgheight: CGFloat = CGFloat(height)

        // See what size is longer and create the center off of that
        if contextSize.width > contextSize.height {
            posX = ((contextSize.width - contextSize.height) / 2)
            posY = 0
            cgwidth = contextSize.height
            cgheight = contextSize.height
        } else {
            posX = 0
            posY = ((contextSize.height - contextSize.width) / 2)
            cgwidth = contextSize.width
            cgheight = contextSize.width
        }

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cgwidth, height: cgheight)

        // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
        let imageRef: CGImage = cgimage.cropping(to: rect)!

        // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

        return image
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have width/height parameters?

Comment: let cgimage = image.cgImage!
        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)
These 2 lines are not necessary.  You are converting the UIImage to CGImage and back.

Comment: let cgimage = image.cgImage! let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage) These 2 lines are needed to make a contextImage with a scale of 1.0

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer only does squares for me. I needed a bit more flexible cropping mechanism so I wrote an extension as follows:

> import UIKit

```
extension UIImage {

func crop(to:CGSize) -> UIImage {

    guard let cgimage = self.cgImage else { return self }

    let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)

    guard let newCgImage = contextImage.cgImage else { return self }

    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

    //Set to square
    var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
    let cropAspect: CGFloat = to.width / to.height

    var cropWidth: CGFloat = to.width
    var cropHeight: CGFloat = to.height

    if to.width > to.height { //Landscape
        cropWidth = contextSize.width
        cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
        posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
    } else if to.width < to.height { //Portrait
        cropHeight = contextSize.height
        cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
        posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
    } else { //Square
        if contextSize.width >= contextSize.height { //Square on landscape (or square)
            cropHeight = contextSize.height
            cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
            posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
        }else{ //Square on portrait
            cropWidth = contextSize.width
            cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
            posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
        }
    }

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight)

    // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
    guard let imageRef: CGImage = newCgImage.cropping(to: rect) else { return self}

    // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
    let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(to, false, self.scale)
    cropped.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: to.width, height: to.height))
    let resized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resized ?? self
  }
}
```

You can use it so:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
let image = UIImage(named: "my_great_photo")?.crop(size)
```

If anyone has ideas how to make the landscape, portrait and square handling a bit better let me know.

Comment: I am using the above extension to crop the image inside a table view cell, and it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 13):

You can try this answer.
It is written in swift 3.

```
extension UIImage {
  func crop(to:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    guard let cgimage = self.cgImage else { return self }

    let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)

    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

    //Set to square
    var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
    let cropAspect: CGFloat = to.width / to.height

    var cropWidth: CGFloat = to.width
    var cropHeight: CGFloat = to.height

    if to.width > to.height { //Landscape
        cropWidth = contextSize.width
        cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
        posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
    } else if to.width < to.height { //Portrait
        cropHeight = contextSize.height
        cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
        posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
    } else { //Square
        if contextSize.width >= contextSize.height { //Square on landscape (or square)
            cropHeight = contextSize.height
            cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
            posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
        }else{ //Square on portrait
            cropWidth = contextSize.width
            cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
            posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
        }
    }

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x : posX, y : posY, width : cropWidth, height : cropHeight)

    // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
    let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!

    // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
    let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)

    cropped.draw(in: CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width : to.width, height : to.height))

    return cropped
  }
}
```

Comment: Works nice with big images but also leaving space from sides with small images.

Answer (score 9):

This is THE answer, credit to @awolf ([Cropping an UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage/18602671#18602671)). Handles scale and orientation perfectly. Just call this method on the image you want to crop, and pass in the cropping `CGRect` without worrying about scale or orientation. Feel free to check whether `cgImage` is nil instead of force unwrapping it like I did here.

```
extension UIImage {
    func croppedInRect(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        func rad(_ degree: Double) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(degree / 180.0 * .pi)
        }

        var rectTransform: CGAffineTransform
        switch imageOrientation {
        case .left:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad(90)).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -self.size.height)
        case .right:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad(-90)).translatedBy(x: -self.size.width, y: 0)
        case .down:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad(-180)).translatedBy(x: -self.size.width, y: -self.size.height)
        default:
            rectTransform = .identity
        }
        rectTransform = rectTransform.scaledBy(x: self.scale, y: self.scale)

        let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect.applying(rectTransform))
        let result = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        return result
    }
}
```

If you want the cropping rect to be centered, just do simple math. Along the lines of

```
let x = (image.width - croppingFrame.width) / 2
```

Another note: if you are working with `imageView` embedded in a `scrollView`, there is one additional step, you have to take the zoom factor into account. Assuming your `imageView` spans the entire content view of the `scrollView`, and you use the bounds of the `scrollView` as the cropping frame, the cropped image can be obtained as

```
let ratio = imageView.image!.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
let origin = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x * ratio, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y * ratio)
let size = CGSize(width: scrollView.bounds.size.width * ratio, let height: scrollView.bounds.size.height * ratio)
let cropFrame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
let croppedImage = imageView.image!.croppedInRect(rect: cropFrame)
```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a code that will give a desired cropped aspect ratio, regardless of original video frame size (adapted from @Cole's answer):

```
func cropImage(uncroppedImage: UIImage, cropWidth: CGFloat, cropHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: uncroppedImage.cgImage!)

        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size
        var cropX: CGFloat = 0.0
        var cropY: CGFloat = 0.0
        var cropRatio: CGFloat = CGFloat(cropWidth/cropHeight)
        var originalRatio: CGFloat = contextSize.width/contextSize.height
        var scaledCropHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        var scaledCropWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

        // See what size is longer and set crop rect parameters
        if originalRatio > cropRatio {

            scaledCropHeight = contextSize.height
            scaledCropWidth = (contextSize.height/cropHeight) * cropWidth
            cropX = (contextSize.width - scaledCropWidth) / 2
            cropY = 0

        } else {
            scaledCropWidth = contextSize.width
            scaledCropHeight = (contextSize.width/cropWidth) * cropHeight
            cropY = (contextSize.height / scaledCropHeight) / 2
            cropX = 0
        }

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: cropX, y: cropY, width: scaledCropWidth, height: scaledCropHeight)

        // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
        let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!

        // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation

        let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: uncroppedImage.scale, orientation: uncroppedImage.imageOrientation)

        return croppedImage
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: To crop image equally from top and bottom (crop from centerY), please change

cropY = (contextSize.height / scaledCropHeight) / 2

to

cropY = (contextSize.height - scaledCropHeight) / 2

Answer (score 3):

### Props to Cole

**Swift 3**

```
func crop(image: UIImage, withWidth width: Double, andHeight height: Double) -> UIImage? {
    
    if let cgImage = image.cgImage {
        
        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        
        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size
        
        var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
        var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
        var cgwidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(width)
        var cgheight: CGFloat = CGFloat(height)
        
        // See what size is longer and create the center off of that
        if contextSize.width > contextSize.height {
            posX = ((contextSize.width - contextSize.height) / 2)
            posY = 0
            cgwidth = contextSize.height
            cgheight = contextSize.height
        } else {
            posX = 0
            posY = ((contextSize.height - contextSize.width) / 2)
            cgwidth = contextSize.width
            cgheight = contextSize.width
        }
        
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cgwidth, height: cgheight)
        
        // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
        var croppedContextImage: CGImage? = nil
        if let contextImage = contextImage.cgImage {
            if let croppedImage = contextImage.cropping(to: rect) {
                croppedContextImage = croppedImage
            }
        }
        
        // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
        if let croppedImage:CGImage = croppedContextImage {
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
            return image
        }
        
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The parameters of this method doesn't have any effect on the result

Answer (score 3):

**Working Swift 3 example**

```
extension UIImage {

    func crop(to:CGSize) -> UIImage {
        guard let cgimage = self.cgImage else { return self }

        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)

        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

        //Set to square
        var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
        var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
        let cropAspect: CGFloat = to.width / to.height

        var cropWidth: CGFloat = to.width
        var cropHeight: CGFloat = to.height

        if to.width > to.height { //Landscape
            cropWidth = contextSize.width
            cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
            posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
        } else if to.width < to.height { //Portrait
            cropHeight = contextSize.height
            cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
            posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
        } else { //Square
            if contextSize.width >= contextSize.height { //Square on landscape (or square)
                cropHeight = contextSize.height
                cropWidth = contextSize.height * cropAspect
                posX = (contextSize.width - cropWidth) / 2
            }else{ //Square on portrait
                cropWidth = contextSize.width
                cropHeight = contextSize.width / cropAspect
                posY = (contextSize.height - cropHeight) / 2
            }
        }

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight)
        // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
        let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!

        // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
        let cropped: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(to, true, self.scale)
        cropped.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: to.width, height: to.height))
        let resized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resized!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just crop using:

```
let croppedImage = yourImage.cgImage.cropping(to:rect)
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 4.1 I would do simply:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

Credits to [Stretching, Redrawing and Positioning with contentMode](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also, very simply, put the concerned ImageView in "Aspect Fill" mode from the Storyboard, and add this in the code :

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer did not work for me, so I tried wrote my own. Here is an effect of my work:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func cropedToRatio(ratio: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let newImageWidth = size.height * ratio

        let cropRect = CGRect(x: ((size.width - newImageWidth) / 2.0) * scale,
                              y: 0.0,
                              width: newImageWidth * scale,
                              height: size.height * scale)

        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let newCgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect) else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: newCgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
}
```

This function crop image to given ratio. It keeps image scale. Cropped image is always center of original image.

Answer (score 2):

Or make UImage extension

```
extension UIImage {
    func cropped(boundingBox: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage?.cropping(to: boundingBox) else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
masklayer.frame = ImgView.frame
```

To this:

```
masklayer.frame = ImgView.bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use Alamofire and AlamofireImage to crop your image.

https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Installing using CocoaPods
`pod 'AlamofireImage'`

Usage:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "unicorn")!
let size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
// Scale image to size disregarding aspect ratio
let scaledImage = image.af_imageScaled(to: size)
let aspectScaledToFitImage = image.af_imageAspectScaled(toFit: size)

// Scale image to fill specified size while maintaining aspect ratio
let aspectScaledToFillImage = image.af_imageAspectScaled(toFill: size)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
extension UIImage {
    /// A function who takes in a uiimage and crops it to its largest square value
    /// - Returns: The cropped image. Nil if the data could not be extracted from the UIImage
    internal func croppedToSquare() -> UIImage? {
        guard let sourceImageData = self.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
    
        let shortestSide = min(self.size.width, self.size.height)
    
        // Determines the x,y coordinate of the top-left corner of the cropped photo
        /// The distance from the leading edge of the original photo to the leading edge of the cropped photo (should be 0 for photos in portrait orientation)
        let xOffset = (self.size.width - shortestSide) / 2
        /// The distance from the top edge of the original photo to the top edge of the cropped photo (should be 0 for photos in landscape orientation)
        let yOffset = (self.size.height - shortestSide) / 2
    
        /// A boolean which indicates if the image data is a rotation (reflections don't matter) of the uiimage. If so, they x and y coordinates should be transposed.
        let axesAreFlipped = self.imageOrientation == .left || self.imageOrientation == .right
        /// The square to crop the image through, with the x, y coordinate describing the top left corner of the square
        let cropMask = CGRect(x: axesAreFlipped ? yOffset : xOffset, y: axesAreFlipped ? xOffset : yOffset, width: shortestSide, height: shortestSide).integral
    
        guard let newImageData = sourceImageData.cropping(to: cropMask) else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return UIImage(cgImage: newImageData, scale: self.imageRendererFormat.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
    }
}
```

This function works by extracting the CGImage data from the given UIImage, then, finding the coordinate of the top left corner of the photo. From this coordinate, a rectangle is drawn with equal sides (the side length being the shortest side of the original image).

Note that the CGImage data describes the data for the **original photo wrapped in the UIImage**- not what is actually displayed by the UIImage by default. Thus, the original orientation of the image needs to be checked to determine if the x and y values need to be flipped.