# How to crop UIImage to mask in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, crop

I have a UIImage that I mask using another UIImage. The only problem is area outside the masked UIImage is still user interactable. How do I completely crop a UIImage to another image instead of mask.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let imageMask = UIImageView()

    imageMask.image = //image to mask

    imageMask.frame = photoImageView.bounds
    imageView.mask = imageMask
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041420/cropping-image-with-swift-and-put-it-on-center-position I think this question is similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Criteria**

A simple test case could define a background color for the view of the ViewController and load the image and mask. Then a UITapGestureRecognizer is added to the ViewController view and to the UIImageView.

When applying a background color to the ViewController view, it is easy to see if masking works.

If you then tap on a non-transparent area, the tap should be received by the UIImageView, otherwise the ViewController view should receive the tap.

**Image and Mask Image Size**

In most cases, the image and mask image size or at least the aspect ratio of the image and mask image is the same. 
It makes sense to use the same `contentMode` for the masking of UIImageView as for the original UIImageView, otherwise there would be a misalignment when changing the content mode in InterfaceBuilder at the latest.

**Test Case**

Therefore the test case could look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    private let maskView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "testimage")
        self.maskView.image = UIImage(named: "mask")
        self.imageView.mask = maskView

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backgroundTapped))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        let imageViewGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(iamgeViewTapped))
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageViewGestureRecognizer)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.maskView.contentMode = self.imageView.contentMode
        self.maskView.frame = self.imageView.bounds
    }

    @objc private func backgroundTapped() {
        print ("background tapped!")
    }

    @objc private func iamgeViewTapped() {
        print ("image view tapped!")
    }

}
```

This code is already running. As expected, however, taps on the transparent area of the UIImageView also get here.

**CustomImageView**

Therefore we need a CustomImageView, which returns when clicking on a transparent pixel that it is not responsible for it.

This can be achieved by overriding this method:

```
func point(inside point: CGPoint, 
      with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

see documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622533-point

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver contains the specified point.

There is this cool answer already on SO, that is just slightly adapted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27923457

```
import UIKit

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return self.alphaFromPoint(point: point) > 32
    }

    private func alphaFromPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UInt8 {
        var pixel: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let alphaInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        if let context = CGContext(data: &pixel,
                                   width: 1,
                                   height: 1,
                                   bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                   bytesPerRow: 4,
                                   space: colorSpace,
                                   bitmapInfo: alphaInfo.rawValue) {
            context.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
            self.layer.render(in: context)
        }
        return pixel[3]
    }

}
```

Don't forget to change the custom class of ImageView to `CustomImageView` in Xcode in the identity inspector.

If you now tap on transparent areas, the view of the ViewController in the background gets the tap. If you tap on non-transparent areas our image view receives the tap.

**Demo**

Here is a short demo of the above code using the image and mask from the question:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question exactly