# How to make UIImage of specific CGRect in view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgrect

I have a full screen image displayed and what I would like to do is be able to provide a CGRect and using that rect get the area (or the rect) of the full screen image that is within it and create a UIImage of it. How can I accomplish this? I've been racking my brain over this one so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cropping an UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code !

```js
UIImage* crop(UIImage *image, rect) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, [image scale]);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y)];
    cropped_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return cropped_image;
}
```