# Pick image and crop image became low quality iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I can pick the image from gallery and then crop the image but it becomes too low quality.

```
CGRect value=  AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageView.image.size, imageView.frame);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.image.size);
[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, value.size.width, value.size.height)];
UIImage *img= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Please any one help me figure out this issue.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your context with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, and pass In a scale of 0. The call UIGraphicsBeginImageContext does not allow for retina images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing in my one project:

```
   //*************** This one creates blury image so used contextWith options *****************************//

   // UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(signView.bounds.size.width, signView.bounds.size.height));

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(signView.bounds.size, signView.opaque, 0.0);

    [signView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    // UIImage *imgMySignature = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    signView.img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here I am rendering image from `UIView`. `signView` is object of `UIView`.

Main concern is, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.