# UIImage userInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an app that takes an image and checks if it is an landscape image,

if so, the app asks the user if he wants to present it as a square image or as a full landscape image.

On this view I use the `UIImageView` `contentMode` to display the image as a square or as a landscape image (`ScaleAspectFill` for square and `ScaleAspectFit` for landscape),

but how can I convert this information to the actual photo?

I want it to be presented in the way the user chose on first view but I can't understand how can I save the user choice into the photo.

Is there something like `userInfo` for `UIImage`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You should save the user's choice in a separate variable.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I mean. there is a lot of photos, how can I know what the user chose in what photo?

Comment: @F.SO3 Use an array of booleans.

Comment: Is there a way to make the contentMode change on the image itself? And then I can crop the image to a square if the user chose square?

Comment: @F.SO3 Yes you can crop a UIImage. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage

Comment: The question is if I can crop it based to the `ImageView` `contentMode`, is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you talking about a "shortcut" like `imageView.crop(image)` then no.