# Update CGRectMake to CGRect in Swift 3 Automatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cgrectmake

Now that CGRectMake , CGPointMake, CGSizeMake, etc. has been removed in Swift 3.0, is there any way to automatically update all initializations like from `CGRectMake(0,0,w,h) to CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:w,height:h)`. Manual process is.. quite a pain.

Not sure why Apple don't auto convert this when I convert the code to Current Swift Syntax...

Comment: Convert to Current Swift Syntax works for me and converts `CGRectMake(0,0,w,h)` to `CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: w,height: h)`. If it does not work in your case then you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apple actually does provide this feature. All you have to do is go to:

**Edit** > **Convert** > **To Latest Swift Syntax...**

[image]

And then follow the onscreen prompts.

This will solve your syntax issues and you won't have to make new functions for all of the various removed functions.

Comment: it does yeah! for some reasons when I first convert, some files didn't get converted. But when I ran again, it did! I guess must run multiple times until all your files get converted..

Comment: it doesnt do it for me, i've more than once and even after making some changes.

Answer (score 79):

The simplest solution is probably just to redefine the functions Apple took away. Example:

```
func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
}
```

Put that in your module and all calls to `CGRectMake` will work again.

Comment: hmm that's cool! let me see what others think; else, I'll accept yours as answers!

Comment: I've been waiting for PaintCode to update to Swift 3. With all the `CGRectMake`s in there, this was by far the best solution.

Comment: Why is there a CGRectMake in the first place if you can init with CGRect the same way, i don't get it

Comment: There used to be `CGRectMake` because Apple hadn't fine-tuned the way Core Graphics is imported into Swift.  They now have, so `CGRectMake` is not available in current Swift releases.

Comment: Obj-C people suffering the migration to Swift :-) That solution is quick and dirty. I'd to it for a quick port. But if you're using Swift, better to just use the paradigm. Not as bad as it seems at first. If I was really bugged by labels, I'd make an extension.  Kind of what you get used to. I've gone back and forth over my career with cryptic/terse vs. long/labeled and they both have advantages. Labels overall make code much easier to maintain and reverse engineer, because after awhile away you do forget and it's a hassle to have to look up every function just to figure out unnamed arguments.

Answer (score 32):

Short answer: don't do it. Don't let Apple boss you around. I *hate* `CGRect(x:y:width:height:)`. I've filed a bug on it. I think the initializer should be `CGRect(_:_:_:_:)`, just like `CGRectMake`. I've defined an extension on CGRect that supplies it, and plop that extension into *every single project* the instant I start.

```
extension CGRect {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)
    }
}
```

That way, all I have to do is change "CGRectMake" to "CGRect" everywhere, and I'm done.

Comment: Thanks for this great helpful answer... You saved my time.

Comment: where can i add this extension? rather, how do i use it? thanks

Comment: @nights, outside any class