# Xcode 8.0 Swift 3, do not match any available overloads error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I used cocoa pods to install DynamicColor and SnappingStepper.  How do I fix the compiler error on the "let stepper" line.

Error: Argument labels'(*:,*:,*:,*:)' do not match any available overloads 
When I post this error, the underscore character is not displayed but the _character should be in front of each colon.

```
import UIKit
import DynamicColor
import SnappingStepper


class ViewController: UIViewController {



let stepper = SnappingStepper(frame: CGRect (0, 0, 100, 40))

func stepperValueChangedAction(sender: AnyObject) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    stepper.addTarget(self, action: "stepperValueChangedAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    view.addSubview(stepper)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
let stepper = SnappingStepper(frame: CGRect (x:0, y:0, width:100, height:40))
```

[After you've fixed that, your code will still have numerous problems; but that answers the particular question you asked.)

Comment: But see also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38361239/341994

Comment: Yes there were 5 or 6 more errors after I corrected the 'let' line.  I got them all fixed and it compiles and runs in the Sim.

Comment: Cool! But do see the other answer I pointed you to: I think you _should_ be able to say `CGRect (0, 0, 100, 40)` and I provide code that allows you to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I originally copied the "Usage" from the Git site, it had several errors that I corrected before I even posted here.  I have all the errors fixed now and it compiles and runs in the Sim.  Would you know how to place a Snapping Stepper component on the storyboard???

Comment: Well I added the extension CGRect immediately below the import SnappingStepper, and eliminated the x: y: Width: height: on my 'let' line.  It compiled and ran.  However I also did an Edit/Convert/To Current Swift Syntax as suggested by one of the posters to that link and now I have 28 errors!!!!!  Was that a mistake?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The errors are probably not real. If it compiles, it compiles and that's that!

Comment: Since I'm a newbie here, I can only ask a question every 4 or 5 days.  Its a lot of wasted time.

Comment: I did a Product/Clean and all but two of the errors left, the two remaining were fixed by removing a semicolon were it didn't belong. Now it compiles and runs.  And now the waiting game to post the "leeched" question.  Thanks again for your help Matt!