# crop and resize image that is selected from gallery or camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, crop, image-resizing

I am new to iOS development and I really need some help in a task. I need to know how does the `cropping` and `re-sizing image` is done in `Objective-C`. For registration I need to select a profile image and then I want to crop and resize it, But I am unaware how to do it. I have seen many source codes in `Github` and at `SO` but none of them seems to help out. Can anyone guide me how does the cropping image work in iOS?

Here is the screenshot of my page I'm working on-

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [use this lib](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tocropviewcontroller)

Comment: I am using This lib https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor easy to use and easy to modify according to requirements

Answer (score 2):

Why you are not using standard UIImagePickerController? If you set `imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;` and then in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method get

```
UIImage *newImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

you'll get the image cropped by user.

Comment: anything else without it ?

Comment: Do you need a separate peace of code for image cropping? I read, you've already searched SO, but have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7704399/3102949) ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function
Pass an image and size in it and get image in return.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;

{

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;

}
```

Comment: I have to crop the image not only resize it