# Why is cgImage?.cropping rotating the image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage

I have written a `UICropperViewController` and it is working perfectly for images in landscape mode. Images in portrait mode have a huge problem. The following picture shows a simple picture with a yellow crop frame:

[image]

The cropping result is:

[image]

Now when it comes to portrait images we got this situation:

[image]

with the following result:

[image]

So what happend here? The original image got automatically rotated to the left.

I researched alot and basically found two suggestions:

**Suggestion 1**

Save the image orientation before cropping and restore it.

```
func didTapCropButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let originalOrientation = self.imageView.image?.imageOrientation;

    // raw value of originalOrientation is `3` so its rotated to the right

    let croppedCGImage = self.imageView.image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: self.cropArea);

    // create a cropped cgImage

    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!, scale: (self.imageView.image?.scale)!, orientation: (originalOrientation)!);

    // create the UIImage with the result from cgImage cropping and original orientation

    if (self.callback != nil) {
        self.callback.croppingDone(image: croppedImage);
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

But the result now is:

[image]

So obviously this suggestion does not work because it is simply rotating back the already cropped image.

**Suggestion 2**

Orientation fixing. I found the following piece of code with the promise that it would fix the error:

```
func didTapCropButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let image = self.imageView.image?.fixOrientation();
    let croppedCGImage = image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: self.cropArea);
    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!);

    if (self.callback != nil) {
        self.callback.croppingDone(image: croppedImage);
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}

extension UIImage {

    /// Extension to fix orientation of an UIImage without EXIF
    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {

        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }

        if imageOrientation == .up { return self }

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        switch imageOrientation {

        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI))

        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))

        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

        case .up, .upMirrored:
            break
        }

        switch imageOrientation {

        case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
            transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)

        case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0)
            transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)

        case .up, .down, .left, .right:
            break
        }

        if let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: cgImage.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) {

            ctx.concatenate(transform)

            switch imageOrientation {

            case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
                ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width))

            default:
                ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            }

            if let finalImage = ctx.makeImage() {
                return (UIImage(cgImage: finalImage))
            }
        }

        // something failed -- return original
        return self
    }
}
```

But this results in a wrong cropping area. The result now could be something like:

[image]

So what could be a real solution for that problem? Anyway, what's the sense of rotating the image automatically if the user does not want it? Is it possible to disable this automatic rotation?

**EDIT**

Complete Source of my Cropper:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CropperCallback {

    func croppingDone(image: UIImage);

    func croppingCancelled();
}

class CropperViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!;
    var imageViewScaleCurrent: CGFloat! = 1.0;
    var imageViewScaleMin: CGFloat! = 0.5;
    var imageViewScaleMax: CGFloat! = 5.0;
    @IBOutlet var cropAreaView: CropAreaView!;
    @IBOutlet weak var cropAreaViewConstraintWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var cropAreaViewConstraintHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var btnCrop: UIButton!;
    @IBOutlet var btnCancel: UIButton!;

    var callback: CropperCallback! = nil;
    var image: UIImage! = nil;
    var imageOriginalWidth: CGFloat!;
    var imageOriginalHeight: CGFloat!;
    var cropWidth: CGFloat! = 287;/
    var cropHeight: CGFloat! = 292;
    var cropHeightFix: CGFloat! = 1.0;
    var cropArea: CGRect {

        get {
            let factor = self.imageView.image!.size.width / self.view.frame.width;
            let scale = 1 / self.imageViewScaleCurrent;
            let x = (self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.x - self.imageView.frame.origin.x) * scale * factor;
            let y = (self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.y - self.imageView.frame.origin.y) * scale * factor;
            let width = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.width * scale * factor;
            let height = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.height * scale * factor;

            return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height);
        }
    }

    static func storyboardInstance() -> CropperViewController? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing:  NSStringFromClass(CropperViewController.classForCoder()).components(separatedBy: ".").last!), bundle: nil);

        return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? CropperViewController;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        /*
        if (self.image.imageOrientation != .up) {
            self.image = UIImage(cgImage: self.image.cgImage!, scale: self.image.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation(rawValue: 0)!);
        }
        */

        self.imageView.image = self.image;
        self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(_:))));
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePinch(_:))));

        self.cropAreaViewConstraintWidth.constant = self.cropWidth;
        self.cropAreaViewConstraintHeight.constant = self.cropHeight;

        self.btnCrop.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapCropButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside);
        self.btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapCancelButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside);
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();

        let imageOriginalRect = self.getRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: self.imageView);

        self.imageOriginalWidth = imageOriginalRect.size.width;
        self.imageOriginalHeight = imageOriginalRect.size.height;

        self.createOverlay();
    }

    func createOverlay() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height));
        let pathRect = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.x, y: self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.y, width: self.cropWidth, height: self.cropHeight));

        path.append(pathRect);
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true;

        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer();
        fillLayer.path = path.cgPath;
        fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
        fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor;
        fillLayer.opacity = 0.1;

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer);
    }

    func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
            let rect = self.getRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: self.imageView);
            let xImage = rect.origin.x;
            let yImage = rect.origin.y;
            let widthImage = rect.size.width;
            let heightImage = rect.size.height;

            let xCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.x;
            let yCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.y;
            let widthCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.width;
            let heightCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.height;

            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view);

            var x: CGFloat;
            var y: CGFloat;

            if (translation.x > 0) {
                if (!(xImage >= xCropView)) {
                    x = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x;
                } else {
                    x = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x;
                }
            } else if (translation.x < 0) {
                if (!((xImage + widthImage) <= (xCropView + widthCropView))) {
                    x = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x;
                } else {
                    x = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x;
                }
            } else {
                x = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x;
            }

            if (translation.y > 0) {
                if (!(yImage >= (yCropView - self.cropHeightFix))) {
                    y = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y;
                } else {
                    y = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y;
                }
            } else if (translation.y < 0) {
                if (!((yImage + heightImage) <= (yCropView + heightCropView + self.cropHeightFix))) {
                    y = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y;
                } else {
                    y = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y;
                }
            } else {
                y = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y;
            }

            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y);
            gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view);

            self.fixImageViewPosition();
        }
    }

    func handlePinch(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = gestureRecognizer.view {
            let widthCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.width;
            let heightCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.height;

            if (((self.imageViewScaleCurrent * gestureRecognizer.scale * self.imageOriginalWidth) > widthCropView)
                && ((self.imageViewScaleCurrent * gestureRecognizer.scale * self.imageOriginalHeight) > (heightCropView + (2 * self.cropHeightFix)))
                && ((self.imageViewScaleCurrent * gestureRecognizer.scale) < self.imageViewScaleMax)) {

                self.imageViewScaleCurrent = self.imageViewScaleCurrent * gestureRecognizer.scale;

                view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.imageViewScaleCurrent, y: self.imageViewScaleCurrent);
            }

            gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0;

            self.fixImageViewPosition();
        }
    }

    func fixImageViewPosition() {
        let rect = self.getRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: self.imageView);
        let xImage = rect.origin.x;
        let yImage = rect.origin.y;
        let widthImage = rect.size.width;
        let heightImage = rect.size.height;

        let xCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.x;
        let yCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.origin.y;
        let widthCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.width;
        let heightCropView = self.cropAreaView.frame.size.height;

        if (xImage > xCropView) {
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xCropView, y: self.imageView.frame.origin.y, width: widthImage, height: heightImage);
        }

        if ((xImage + widthImage) < (xCropView + widthCropView)) {
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: ((xCropView + widthCropView) - widthImage), y: self.imageView.frame.origin.y, width: widthImage, height: heightImage);
        }

        if (yImage > yCropView) {
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.imageView.frame.origin.x, y: (yCropView - self.cropHeightFix), width: widthImage, height: heightImage);
        }

        if ((yImage + heightImage) < (yCropView + heightCropView + self.cropHeightFix)) {
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.imageView.frame.origin.x, y: ((yCropView + heightCropView + self.cropHeightFix) - heightImage), width: widthImage, height: heightImage);
        }
    }

    func getRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: UIImageView) -> CGRect {
        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size;
        let imageSize = imageView.image!.size;

        let scaleW = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width;
        let scaleH = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height;
        let aspect = min(scaleW, scaleH);

        var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (imageSize.width * aspect), height: (imageSize.height * aspect));

        imageRect.origin.x = (imageViewSize.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2;
        imageRect.origin.y = (imageViewSize.height - imageRect.size.height) / 2;

        imageRect.origin.x += imageView.frame.origin.x;
        imageRect.origin.y += imageView.frame.origin.y;

        return imageRect;
    }

    func getCGImageWithCorrectOrientation(_ image : UIImage) -> CGImage {
        if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up) {
            return image.cgImage!;
        }

        var transform : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity;

        switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientation.right, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-1.0 * M_PI_2));
            break;
        case UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2));
            break;
        case UIImageOrientation.down, UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.height, y: 0);
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientation.downMirrored, UIImageOrientation.upMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0);
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        let contextWidth : Int;
        let contextHeight : Int;

        switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored,
             UIImageOrientation.right, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
            contextWidth = (image.cgImage?.height)!;
            contextHeight = (image.cgImage?.width)!;
            break;
        default:
            contextWidth = (image.cgImage?.width)!;
            contextHeight = (image.cgImage?.height)!;
            break;
        }

        let context : CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: contextWidth, height: contextHeight,
                                            bitsPerComponent: image.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
                                            bytesPerRow: image.cgImage!.bytesPerRow,
                                            space: image.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                                            bitmapInfo: image.cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!;

        context.concatenate(transform);
        context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(contextWidth), height: CGFloat(contextHeight)));

        let cgImage = context.makeImage();

        return cgImage!;
    }

    func didTapCropButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let fixedImage = self.getCGImageWithCorrectOrientation(self.imageView.image!);

        // let image = self.imageView.image?.fixOrientation();

        let croppedCGImage = fixedImage.cropping(to: self.cropArea);
        let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!);

        if (self.callback != nil) {
            self.callback.croppingDone(image: croppedImage);
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

    func didTapCancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (self.callback != nil) {
            self.callback.croppingCancelled();
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}

extension UIImageView {

    func imageFrame() -> CGRect {
        let imageViewSize = self.frame.size;

        guard let imageSize = self.image?.size else {
            return CGRect.zero;
        }

        let imageRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;
        let imageViewRatio = imageViewSize.width / imageViewSize.height;

        if (imageRatio < imageViewRatio) {
            let scaleFactor = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height;
            let width = imageSize.width * scaleFactor;
            let topLeftX = (imageViewSize.width - width) * 0.5;

            return CGRect(x: topLeftX, y: 0, width: width, height: imageViewSize.height);
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width;
            let height = imageSize.height * scaleFactor;
            let topLeftY = (imageViewSize.height - height) * 0.5;

            return CGRect(x: 0, y: topLeftY, width: imageViewSize.width, height: height);
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    // Extension to fix orientation of an UIImage without EXIF

    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
            return self;
        }

        if self.imageOrientation == .up {
            return self;
        }

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity;

        switch self.imageOrientation {
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI));
        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2));
        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2));
        case .up, .upMirrored:
            break;
        }

        switch self.imageOrientation {
        case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
            transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0);
            transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
        case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.height, y: 0);
            transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
        case .up, .down, .left, .right:
            break;
        }

        if let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(self.size.width), height: Int(self.size.height), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: cgImage.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) {
            ctx.concatenate(transform);

            switch self.imageOrientation {
            case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
                ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.height, height: self.size.width));
            default:
                ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height));
            }

            if let finalImage = ctx.makeImage() {
                return (UIImage(cgImage: finalImage));
            }
        }

        // something failed -- return original
        return self;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage/14712184#14712184 for a very simple implementation that rotates the crop rect instead of the entire image. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602671/669586 is a very simple solution.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to understand the `scale` and `orientation` properties.

Your suggestion 1 (use the orientation of the original image) is obviously a correct suggestion and it would work, if you were able to also rotate and scale your `cropArea`.

Your suggestion 2 is a good to handle rotation but you still have to *scale* the `cropArea`. Currently you are not handling the scale at all.

(minor note, rotating `cropArea` would probably have better performance than rotating the whole image, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712184/669586).

You have to:

1. Scale (multiply) `cropArea` by the scale of the image.
2. Use the original image scale when creating the result

For example, if your `UIImage` has size `200x100` and it has scale `2x` (it's a retina image), your `cgImage` will have size `400x200` but you are still working with a crop area inside `200x100`!

Something along the lines of:

```
func didTapCropButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let image = self.imageView.image else {
        return
    }

    let cgImage = self.getCGImageWithCorrectOrientation(image);

    let scaledCropArea = CGRect(
        x: self.cropArea.x * image.scale,
        y: self.cropArea.y * image.scale,
        width: self.cropArea.width * image.scale,
        height: self.cropArea.height * image.scale
    )

    let croppedCGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: scaledCropArea)
    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: .up)

    if (self.callback != nil) {
        self.callback.croppingDone(image: croppedImage)
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The automatic rotation and transforms in `UIImage` are simply an optimization. Thanks to this optimization, multiple images can share the same storage (the same memory data). The optimization is done already in your asset loader and you cannot disable it.

Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602671/669586 for a simpler and safer implementation.

Comment: The scaling does not seem to be the problem with suggestion 1. The result is a landscape cropped picture where it should be a portrait scaled picture. With suggestion 1 all that happens is: rotate from portrait to landscape, crop, rotate back. If not I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: @Mulgard I looked wrong. The `cropArea` must be rotated. I will inspect your second suggestion in more detail.

Comment: @Mulgard After looking into your code, I think that my original idea was correct. You have to update the scale.

Comment: Have you seen what I did with my `cropArea` variable in the `get` selector. I thought I would perform the scaling of the crop area there.

Comment: @Mulgard I see that you are scaling something but you are not using `image.scale` I think. Also, when creating the result, you have to use the original scale, too. Otherwise your image will have doubled size.